# Solidity contract "burn from" functions not compiling?

Tags: mist

When attempting to compile any solidity contract, errors are returned.  I find myself constantly having to restart the wallet as it gets stuck on both chains, on the test chain it got to the last block and i restarted the wallet and everything seemed to be fine, but contracts must be modified before they will work.  For example, I had to remove  this code from the [create a crypto currency contract code](https://ethereum.org/token#the-code):

```
function burn() payable returns (bool success) {
    if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
    Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}

function burnFrom(address _from) payable returns (bool success) {
    if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
    if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
    Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}
```

If I do not delete this code, the contract will not deploy.

I thought the issue was affecting just Debian, but it's happening on Ubuntu as well.  Strangely enough on Debian, transactions were disappearing, though that's not happening here on Ubuntu, I'm wondering why this is happening.

Comment: what errors are being returned?

Comment: Could not compile source code. 

 Undeclared identifier.
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
                      ^---^
,

Answer (score 1):

The signature of your burnFrom function only specifies one parameter, _from. You need to change it to:

```
function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) payable returns (bool success)
```

EDIT: This answer is only true if you're expecting the value as a param

Comment: This didn't work either (see comment below)

Comment: Operator < not compatible with types uint256 and int256
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
            ^-----------------------^
,

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I edited my answer - it's not int, it's uint.